# Laravel select 3 rows from the same table with different value for a specified column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, distinct

In my database is stored a table called 'advertisement' with the following records:

```
id |   code      | position
 1 |   header1   | header
 2 |   header2   | header
 3 |   header3   | header
 4 |   footer1   | footer
 5 |   footer2   | footer
 6 |   banner1   | banner
 7 |   banner2   | banner
```

I need to pick only one record for each 'position'. For example an output could be:

```
 1 |   header1   | header
 5 |   footer2   | footer
 7 |   banner2   | banner
```

How can I achieve this?

```
Advertisement::where(...)->distinct()->get();
```

This didn't do the magic because it's giving me distinct values considering all the columns, not only 'position'

Comment: You mean `groupBy()`?

Comment: @JoelHinz If I use groupBy('position') I'll get only one row as result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using groupBy()

```
Advertisement::groupBy('position')->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this query is giving me only one record as result. I need to get three different records.

Comment: Can you write the exact code that you are using for groupBy() ?